# Lucene.Net 4.8 add multiple filters to custom analyzer

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm attempting to create a custom analyser with multiple filters applied.

The issue is only the last filter (LowerCaseFilter) is applied.

```
public class CustomAnalyzer : Analyzer
        {
            protected override TokenStreamComponents CreateComponents(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
            {

                Tokenizer tokenizer = new KeywordTokenizer(reader);

                //Remove basic stop words a, an, the, in, on etc

                TokenStream result = new StopFilter(GlobalVariables.LuceneVersion, tokenizer, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);

                ////Remove tile/tiles
                CharArraySet stopWords = new CharArraySet(GlobalVariables.LuceneVersion, 1, true)
                {
                    "test",
                    }

                result = new  StopFilter(GlobalVariables.LuceneVersion, tokenizer, stopWords);

                //Make case insenstive
                result = new LowerCaseFilter(GlobalVariables.LuceneVersion, tokenizer);

                return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, result);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass the tokenizer into each filter, pass the previous filter in.

```
Tokenizer tokenizer = new KeywordTokenizer(reader);
TokenStream result = new StopFilter(GlobalVariables.LuceneVersion, tokenizer, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);
CharArraySet stopWords = new CharArraySet(GlobalVariables.LuceneVersion, 1, true)
result = new  StopFilter(GlobalVariables.LuceneVersion, result, stopWords);
result = new LowerCaseFilter(GlobalVariables.LuceneVersion, result);
return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, result);
```